# Automatic derivation of Data.Vector.Unbox with associated type synonyms

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, type-families, deriving

I have a datatype

```
newtype Zq q = Zq (IntType q)
```

where 'q' will be an instance of the class

```
class Foo a where
   type IntType a
```

and 'IntType' is just the underlying representation (i.e. Int, Integral, etc) associated with 'q'.

I want to make Zq an instance of [Data.Vector.Unbox](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html). We are currently manually deriving Unbox using about 50 lines of trivial code as suggested in the link above. We will be making several different types 'Unbox' in our code, so writing 50 lines for each type is not appealing.

I found two alternatives [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/17252). One alternative is to use [this package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-th-unbox/0.1.0.0/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed-Deriving.html) which uses Template Haskell to derive instances of Unbox. The TH code would look like:

```
derivingUnbox "Zq"
  [d| instance (Foo q, U.Unbox (IntType q)) => Unbox' (ZqBasic q) (IntType q) |]
  [| \ (Zq x) -> x |]
  [| \ x -> Zq x |]
```

The problem is, I [can't define instances using associated type synonyms](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2008-October/015794.html) (or can I??)

[A related question: Why does [TypeSynonymInstances](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/TypeSynonymInstances), an extension implied by FlexibleInstances, not allow **associated** type synonym instances? Is this somehow fundamentally a different beast?]

My current solution to that problem is to redefine Zq as

```
newtype Zq q i = Zq i
```

and then add the equality constraint

```
i~(IntType q)
```

in every instance involving (Zq q i), which isn't very elegant. My (working) Unbox derivation becomes

```
derivingUnbox "Zq"
  [d| instance (U.Unbox i, i~IntType q, Foo q) => Unbox' (Zq q i) i |]
  [| \ (Zq x) -> x |]
  [| \ x -> Zq x |]
```

I feel like I should be able to accomplish this without resorting to explicitly exposing the type 'i'. All I've done is moved it from an associated type synonym to an explicit parameter with equality constraints. Why is this "fundamentally" a different (and apparently safer) approach? Is there some way I can avoid adding the type parameter 'i' and still get automatic Unbox derivation?

Extra type parameter aside, I'm having trouble using the TH package to derive Unbox for (Vector r), that is, I want to make an Unbox Vector of Unbox Vectors. My attempt is something like:

```
newtype Bar r = Bar (Vector r)

derivingUnbox "Bar"
  [d| instance (Unbox r) => Unbox' (Bar r) (Vector r) |]
  [| \ (Bar x) -> x |]
  [| \ x -> Bar x |]
```

but I get (lots of) errors like:

```
`basicUnsafeFreeze` is not a (visible) method of class `Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector`
```

I'm not sure why it can't find this method, when it works just fine for my Zq type.

---

The second approach listed [above](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/17252) is using the extension GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving. The biggest problem I see with this approach is that I have some actual Data (rather than Newtype) that I need to be Unbox. However, just using the extension, I should be able to write

```
newtype Zq q = Zq (IntType q) deriving (Unbox, M.MVector MVector, G.Vector Vector)
```

or at least

```
newtype Zq q i = Zq i deriving (Unbox, M.MVector MVector, G.Vector Vector)
```

The first leads to the errors:

```
No instance for (Unbox (IntType q)) arising from the `deriving` clause of a data type declaration
No instance for (M.MVector MVector (IntType q)) ""
No instance for (G.Vector Vector (IntType q)) ""
```

and the second gives:

```
No instance for (M.MVector MVector i) ""
No instance for (G.Vector U.Vector i) ""
```

I'm not sure why it can't derive these instances, as the post above leads me to believe it should be able to. Perhaps I could get away with using the associated type synonym with GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving? (This still (probably) doesn't solve my problem when I need to derive Unbox for 'data's.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `Vector a` is not, and probably should never be, an instance of `Unbox`.  Why do you think it would make sense?  `Unbox` types should generally be types that have a fixed-size representation in bytes, which is not the case for `Vector a`.  The only possible alternative would be an `Unbox` instance that secretly doesn't do any unboxing, and uses a normal `Data.Vector.Vector`, but I'm not sure there's any point to that.

Comment: I'm not sure if this could make a difference or not, but the type "Bar r" above is really "Bar m r" in our program, and 'm' uniquely determines the size of the vector (admittedly, not in any way the compiler could tell I think). Could we use this somehow to make unbox vectors, or should we just stick with normal Vector.Vectors? Either way, the questions about the Unbox derivation for Zq still stands.

Comment: You may be able to use that to make unboxed vectors, I suppose, but you're definitely not going to be able to automatically derive the implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into a few separate problems here:

### The TH approach

#### Yes, class instances for associated type synonyms are illegal

It's true that you can't define class instances for associated type synonyms or type functions, and this is with good reason: the compiler can't tell whether they overlap. For instance:

```
type family F a
instance Eq (F Int)
instance Eq (F Bool)
```

Do these instances overlap? Given the above source code, we can't tell: it depends on how someone later defines instances for `F`. For instance, they could define

```
type instance F Int = Double
type instance F Bool = Double
```

and then the two instances of `Eq` would in fact be overlapping.

#### You're running into a problem with the `vector-th-unbox` package

If you look at the actual `Unbox` instance you want, you don't actually want an instance for `IntType q`; what you want is simply this:

```
instance (Unbox (IntType q), Foo q) => Unbox (Zq q) where
    ...
```

The problem is that the `vector-th-unbox` package forces you to use the fake type-class `Unbox'` to communicate the intermediate representation type (`IntType q` in your case), as a convenient way of abusing Template Haskell's syntax to pass in a type. And then GHC sees that you have written `Unbox' (Zq q) (IntType q)` and complains. I would suggest filing a bug for the `vector-th-unbox` package.

### `Unbox` for `Vector r`

I think Louis Wasserman covered this.

### The `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` approach

The specific compile error you're having is because GHC can't infer the appropriate context. For most problems similar to the one you're having, `StandaloneDeriving` language extension would solve your problem:

```
deriving instance Unbox (IntType q) => Unbox (Zq q)
deriving instance Unbox (IntType q) => M.MVector MVector (Zq q)
deriving instance Unbox (IntType q) => G.Vector Vector (Zq q)
```

#### But DON'T do this!

While `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` often does exactly what you want, it is broken in [some fundamental ways](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1496), and the `Unbox` instance it produces is [completely broken](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/17315)! So stick with the TH approach, after lobbying Liyang for a fix for your current problem.

Answer (score 4):

I've changed the syntax in [4820b73](https://github.com/liyang/vector-th-unbox/commit/4820b730b19716026aadc17176355710c109aafa), so you should be able to do what you want now:

```
derivingUnbox "Complex"
    [d| (Unbox a) ⇒ Complex a → (a, a) |]
    [| \ (r :+ i) → (r, i) |]
    [| \ (r, i) → r :+ i |]
```

I've also fixed the “xyz is not a (visible) method…” errors in [fe37976](https://github.com/liyang/vector-th-unbox/commit/fe379761bcf03699bbb6e0b272981042bfe4c9b4), although it was possible to work around it with:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable
```

Out now on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-th-unbox-0.2).
CC: @reinerp

Comment: It makes me cry that I have to add 3 extensions and a package for such a seemingly simple thing, but thanks for at least providing the heavy lifting for us in a package!